# Не работает вывод ошибки mat-error, использую Custom Validation

Tags: angular2

Мой input-container состоит mat-error блока

```
<mat-input-container *ngIf="isUpdate">
        <input [formControl]="dateFormControl" matInput (ngModelChange)="changeDate($event)"
             [ngModel] = "data.date | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm'" placeholder="date">
        <mat-error *ngIf="dateFormControl.hasError('errorDate')">
            past date
        </mat-error>
    </mat-input-container>
```

Я создал функцию в моем .ts файле, там же где и находится formControl

```
function errorDate(c: FormControl) {
    const date = new Date(c.value);
    return date.valueOf() > Date.now() ? null : {
        validateDate: {
            valid: false
        }
    };
}
```

которая определяет что дата меньше чем текущая

и я определил ее в FormControl

```
dateFormControl = new FormControl('', [
        errorDate
    ]);
```

Я получаю такой результат

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

но я хочу получить подпись с ошибкой под моим полем ввода

что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dateFormControl.hasError('validateDate')
```

- это будет работать, чтобы посмотреть список ошибок можно воспользоваться `consgole.log(this.dateFormControl.errors);`

Answer (score 0):

в темплейте идет ссылка на атрибут формы 'errorDate'.

Вот и ошибку с этим именем и надо возвращать в своей функции

```
return date.valueOf() > Date.now() ? null : {
        validateDate: {
            errorDate: false
        }
    };
```

Comment: Ничего не изменилось